# Angular 8 BrowserAnimations error with AOT

Tags: angular, angular-animations, angular2-aot

I have `route-animations.ts` that has some animations.
when i run the code with `ng serve` it works fine but i get an error when running with `ng serve --prod`.

```js
export const slider =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('* => isLeft', slideTo('left') ),
    transition('* => isRight', slideTo('right') ),
    transition('isRight => *', slideTo('left') ),
    transition('isLeft => *', slideTo('right') )
  ]);

function slideTo(direction) {
  const optional = { optional: true };
  return [
    query(':enter, :leave', [
      style({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        [direction]: 0,
        width: '100%'
      })
    ], optional),
    query(':enter', [
      style({ [direction]: '-100%'})
    ]),
    group([
      query(':leave', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ [direction]: '100%'}))
      ], optional),
      query(':enter', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ [direction]: '0%'}))
      ])
    ]),
  ];
}
```

i get this error `ERROR in src\app\app.component.ts(14,16): Error during template compile of 'AppComponent'
  Reference to a non-exported function in 'slider'
    'slider' contains the error at src\app\animations\route-animations.ts(41,10).`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { slider } from './animations/route-animations';;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  animations: [slider]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() { }

  prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
  }


}
```

Comment: how does that work without ao? you have function name `slider` imported but im not even sure if you export `slideTo` it looks like something is missing in what you are showing

Comment: @Xesenix thank you, I have edited my question you can see I export it

Comment: I guess the solution to that error would be also export `export function slideTo`

Comment: @Xesenix now i get this error `ERROR in src\app\app.component.ts(14,16): Error during template compile of 'AppComponent'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'slideTo' was called in 'slider'
    'slider' calls 'slideTo'.`

Comment: this bug report may be related https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15587

Comment: @KLTR did you find any solution? I am facing this same issue.

Comment: @Divya yes,i altered the animation code to a const that doesn't use any other exported function. i will upload the answer here soon because it is too long for a comment :)

Comment: @KLTR i want to apply transition on multiple routes. What if I still have to create another function of "slideTo(direction)" ?

Comment: @Divya it is still possible to use it in every route you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was quite simple, we just have to combine the exported const and function into one const.

````js
export const slider =
trigger('routeAnimations', [
  transition('* => isLeft', [
    query(':enter, :leave', [
      style({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%'
      })
    ], { optional: true }),
    query(':enter', [
      style({ left: '-100%'})
    ]),
    group([
      query(':leave', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ left: '100%'}))
      ], { optional: true }),
      query(':enter', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ left: '0%'}))
      ])
    ]),
  ]),
  transition('* => isRight', [
    query(':enter, :leave', [
      style({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: '100%'
      })
    ], { optional: true }),
    query(':enter', [
      style({ right: '-100%'})
    ]),
    group([
      query(':leave', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ right: '100%'}))
      ], { optional: true }),
      query(':enter', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ right: '0%'}))
      ])
    ]),
  ]),
  transition('isRight => *', [
    query(':enter, :leave', [
      style({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: '100%'
      })
    ], { optional: true }),
    query(':enter', [
      style({ left: '-100%'})
    ]),
    group([
      query(':leave', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ left: '100%'}))
      ], { optional: true }),
      query(':enter', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ left: '0%'}))
      ])
    ]),
  ]),
  transition('isLeft => *', [
    query(':enter, :leave', [
      style({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: '100%'
      })
    ], { optional: true }),
    query(':enter', [
      style({ right: '-100%'})
    ]),
    group([
      query(':leave', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ right: '100%'}))
      ], { optional: true }),
      query(':enter', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ right: '0%'}))
      ])
    ]),
  ])
],
)```
````

Answer (score 2):

Little bit addition to @KLTR's solution.
In case if you want to add same transition on multiple routes, without creating another function, that can be achieved as follow:
Below code can be used to apply left transition on different routes:

```
 export const slider =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
  transition('route1 => route2, route3 => route4, route5 => route6', [
  query(':enter, :leave', [
    style({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100%'
  })
  ], { optional: true }),
  query(':enter', [
    style({ left: '-100%'})
  ]),
  group([
    query(':leave', [
    animate('600ms ease', style({ left: '100%'}))
  ], { optional: true }),
  query(':enter', [
    animate('600ms ease', style({ left: '0%'}))
  ])
  ]),
  ]),
```

Similarly, different transitions can be combined in single exported const (as @KLTR mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

...apparently, less code duplication could be achieved by explicitly exporting dedicated Left and Right counterpart of the slideTo function, like so:

```
export const slider =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('* => isLeft', slideToLeft() ),
    transition('* => isRight', slideToRight() ),
    transition('isRight => *', slideToLeft() ),
    transition('isLeft => *', slideToRight() )
  ]);

const optional = { optional: true };

export function slideToLeft {
  return [
    query(':enter, :leave', [
      style({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%'
      })
    ], optional),
    query(':enter', [
      style({ left: '-100%'})
    ]),
    group([
      query(':leave', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ left: '100%'}))
      ], optional),
      query(':enter', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ left: '0%'}))
      ])
    ]),
  ];
}

export function slideToRight {
  return [
    query(':enter, :leave', [
      style({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: '100%'
      })
    ], optional),
    query(':enter', [
      style({ right: '-100%'})
    ]),
    group([
      query(':leave', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ right: '100%'}))
      ], optional),
      query(':enter', [
        animate('600ms ease', style({ right: '0%'}))
      ])
    ]),
  ];
}
```